# Translating MS Access Query for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to recreate a query that was done in MS Access, and now is being handled in a SQL Server environment. I understand that some of the SQL syntax is different in Access than it is in SQL Server. Is there somewhere online that points out the main differences, or will help translate one to the other?

This is a query that I need to update to use in SQL Server:

```
  UPDATE
    dbo.TPR00100
  INNER JOIN (
    dbo.UPR10302
    LEFT JOIN dbo.B3980280 ON dbo.TPR10302.COMPTRNM = dbo.B3980280.COMPTRNM
  ) ON dbo.TPR00100.STAFFID = dbo.TPR10302.STAFFID
  SET
    dbo.B3980280.COMPTRNM = dbo.TPR10302.comptrnm,
    dbo.B3980280.BI_LOC_ID = dbo.TPR00100.locatnid
  WHERE
    (((dbo.B3980280.COMPTRNM) Is Null))
```

What are they key aspects that need to be handled differently in a SQL Server transaction for this query?

Comment: Aside: Whenever I'm working on translating code from one SQL dialect to another, I find doing a search for "<dialect I'm starting with> <functionality in that dialect> equivalent in <target dialect>" almost always gets me what I need. e.g. "Access CDate equivalent in TSQL".

Comment: @EricBrandt Yeah, not with `UPDATE` or `PIVOT` in Access. T-SQL has no real equivalents for these. An `UPDATE` might have to be rewritten to 3 separate `UPDATE`/`MERGE` queries if it involves multiple tables, a `PIVOT` can only be handled with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If find it handy to use an updateable CTE for this:

```
with cte as (
    select
        b39.comptrnm b39_comptrnm
        b39.bssi_loc_id b39_bssi_loc_id,
        tpr.comptrnm tpr_comptrnm,
        tpr.locatnid tpr_locatnid
    from dbo.tpr00100 tpr
    inner join dbo.upr10302 upr on tpr.staffid = upr.staffid
    inner join dbo.b3980280 b39 on tpr.comptrnm = b39.comptrnm
    where b39_comptrnm is null
)
update cte 
set b39_comptrnm = tpr_comptrnm, b39_bssi_loc_id = tpr_locatnid
```

Note: I am not really sure why the table to update is `left join`ed in the original query, so I turned it to an `inner join .

Comment: Note that this `LEFT JOIN` might be intentional. The equivalent to an `UPDATE`  with a `LEFT JOIN` in Access is a `MERGE` in T-SQL. An `UPDATE` query in Access with an outer join will automatically create new rows on unmatched rows.

Comment: Yes, and while I didn't write the original Access queries, I would assume that was intentional.